# WP7: ListBox.ScrollIntoView smooth scrolling

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

How can i make smooth scrolling of content into ListBox?
I tried to use ListBox.ScrollIntoView but it instantly scrolls to selected item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an animation to achieve that goal - unfortunately the scrolling Horizontal/VerticalOffset cannot be animated directly so you have to animate properties on a mediator object, which then in turn sets the desired values.

There's a full article about this approach [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150624180756/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/delay/archive/2009/08/04/scrolling-so-smooth-like-the-butter-on-a-muffin-how-to-animate-the-horizontal-verticaloffset-properties-of-a-scrollviewer.aspx).

```
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScroller">
        <ScrollViewer.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="ScrollAnimation">
                <!-- Animate from top to bottom -->
                <DoubleAnimation x:Name="VerticalOffsetAnimantion"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Mediator"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="VerticalOffset"
                        Duration="0:0:1">
                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        <!-- Ease in and out -->
                        <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                </DoubleAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
        </ScrollViewer.Resources>
```